# Resetting picklist value back to none onchange

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Picklist 1 values:**
Yes
No

**Picklist2 values:**

one
two
three

I was able to attain the rerendering functionality from the below sample code. If I select *picklist1* value as "yes", I am able to display *picklist2*. And now if I select *picklist2* value as "three" and change *picklist1* value to "No", *Picklist2* value is disappeared from the page, so far so good. Now when I change the *Picklist1* value back to "Yes", the *Picklist2* value is rerendered on page with value as *three*. I want to reset the *Picklist2* value to none. I need similar funtionality to be implemented with all the text and other fields. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks.

**Vfpage**

```
<apex:pageblockSectionItem> <apex:inputfield value="{!picklist1}" onchange="reset();"> </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

<apex:pageblockSectionItem rendered = "{!value}"> <apex:inputfield value="{!picklist2}"> </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

<apex:actionfunction name=reset action="{!check}">
```

**Controller**

```
    public boolean value{get;set};
public void check(){    
    if(picklist1 == 'yes')
    { 
    value=true;
    }
    else{
    value = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because `picklist2` is not rendered, it still retains its value.  If you want it reset back to null each time the `picklist1` value is changed, you need to do this yourself.

It looks as though you are already using an onChange function for your picklist1 value called `reset()`.   You don't show that function here, but you need to reset the controller property value for `picklist2` in that function.  You can do this through an action function or through VF remoting.

> EDIT

Just add a line to your `check()` method that resets the picklist2 value to blank.

```
public void check(){  
    picklist2 = '';  
    if(picklist1 == 'yes') { 
         value=true;
    }
    else{
         value = false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: "Reset()" is a action function(name), on change it goes to action function and calls check() method.                             <apex:actionfunction name=reset action="{!check}">

Comment: Then I would alter check method to reset picklist1 value to null as well as setting the value property.

Comment: ninja: I didn't understand, could you please edit the above code and show what exactly do I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: See edited answer above

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that, as I have many other fields depending on other picklist1, picklist2 and other dependent field options. Is there any other way I could reset the field values?

Comment: You should probably update your question with _all_ of your code and _all_ of your requirements.